# Counting how many times a thread has been preempted?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, pthreads, real-time

I am trying to determine the impact of context switching on my Java thread. Therefore I would have to know first "how many times has it been preempted?" and second, if possible, "how long was my thread suspended from execution?". I would doubt very much that this can be done from Java, but *hey! the fun things is to do the impossible, right?* :) Even If I have to recompile the VM or to use some kind of LINUX tool or hack I would be happy. So now that we know that can't be done, let's do it. :)

EDIT: Come on people. The other question was priority related. I guess you just enjoy easy and boring questions. The question is clear and valid.

Comment: This smacks a lot like premature optimization to me. You are asking for things that a normal JVM does not provide. Can you edit your question and explain why you need to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916876/is-it-possible-to-create-a-high-priority-thread-with-a-regular-jvm-one-that-wil

Comment: Even if it could be done, there is almost no value in this. It's going to depend highly on what CPU your testing, plus a whole lot of other environmental factors, plus variability given what code you are testing with.

Comment: See my edit. This question is clear and valid.

Comment: Maybe `kernelshark` provides that information? Otherwise, `perf` or `oprofile` may show something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can identify the Linux TID (thread ID) for the Java thread you're interested in (assuming your JVM maps Java threads onto Linux threads) then the pseudo-file `/proc/<tid>/status` contains many statistics, including `voluntary_ctxt_switches` and `nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches`.

Answer (score 2):

It clearly doesn't do everything you want, but you may find the [`ThreadMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) available in `java.lang.management` useful.

Comment: That's already something. If contention time has increased that means the thread was blocked / interrupted. And people want to close the question. ts ts ts