# change thread priority in running java program?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

I'm running a large multithreaded java job on a 64-core machine. The program has been running for days and I would like to change the priority of some threads created by java (not of the main thread), but without cancelling and restarting the program, as that would be a large waste of time and computing resources.

Are there any ways to change thread priority *at runtime, from the OS (linux)*? I know the `renice` command in linux can renice the entire process, but I'm looking for a way to change the priority of the created threads at runtime (which doesn't seem to happen with just a renice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your Java and Linux version but you can do this:

Make a thread dump of your application. First `jps` to find the process ID, then `jstack` for a thread dump.

The dump will contain `nid`s:

```
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f322001f800 nid=0x6bd3 runnable
```

That's the PID of the thread in hex. You can use `printf` to convert it to decimal:

```
printf "%d\n" 0x6bd3
```

which gives us 27603.

You can now use `renice` with this PID to change the thread priority.

Sources:

- [How to find a Java thread running on Linux with ps -axl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934517/how-to-find-a-java-thread-running-on-linux-with-ps-axl)
- [What is Java thread priority?](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml) (found in [Setting priority to Java's threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617963/setting-priority-to-javas-threads))
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/chrt

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that JVM threads are connected to the OS in such a way. I delete my answer (which said "You cannot do that"). Thanks!

Comment: You need an Oracle (Sun) VM and Linux. There is no standard/portable/will-always-work solution.